# How to express exact quantifier in this situation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, computer-science, predicate-logic, quantifiers

This is a problem from Discrete Mathematics and its Applications
[image]

My question is on 10g. Here is my work so far. [image]

My logic behind this is to first iterate over all peoples in the world, for each person in the world, again iterate over all peoples in the world. This is going to find a combination of two unique people(bc of x != y) that Nancy can fool. How can i put a quantifier or check to make sure that this is the only combination? After all, one the main tools that I was given [image] represents "there is". It doesn't check exact amount(in this case 2). I don't what this would be called but I tried looking up exact quantifiers(a logical guess) - https://www.google.com/#q=exact+quantifiers
but didn't find anything on this subject - it was all stuff on regular expressions, php, regex, asymmetrics, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you add the fact that x and y are unique is you add a universal quantifier that if anything else satisfies the relationship, then it must be x or y.   So you'd add an $\wedge (\forall w, F(Nancy,w) \implies ((w=x)\vee (w=y))$ to the end of what you have

Comment: would that be another nested quantifier?

Comment: It would go right after your third and term,  before the closing parenthesis

Comment: oh because it needs access to x and y

Comment: Correct, this is the general way you express something is unique...you say that if anything else satisfies the criterea, then it must be equal to the original thing

Comment: Hi Alan, can you take a look at my latest question on proof by contradiction?